# Backup data inside Classic on Palm Pre

Tags: backup, palm-pre

I use a PalmOS app inside Classic on the Palm Pre to store some data.  Is there any way to back up the data?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Red Feline Backup](http://www.dt002.titandsl.co.uk/software/rfbackup.html) - VFS Backup for Palm OS

[image]

Red Feline Backup is a backup program for PalmOS. It does not require a host PC. Instead all databases on your PalmOS device will be copied onto a memory card inserted into the device. then you can copy from your memory card to host PC

Comment: What "memory card" do I use with a Palm Pre?  Do you mean the USB "drive"?  Can Red Feline "see" that from inside Classic?